# how does swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens work and its inputs

Tags: uniswap, cpp-ethereum, function

I tried many things on inputs but unfortunately I am just receving a gas error (the one that says would likely fail if continued)
How does the function input works exactly?

```
            uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
                contractTokenBalance,
                0,
                path,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp);
```

I tried mirroring the contractTokenBalance using BalanceOf

eg.

**Input 1** : 444000000000000000000000 *//444000 token balance in the contract + 18 decimals*

**Input 2** : 0 *//as it says over the code its only 0*

**Input 3** : 0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd *//wBNB testnet*

**Input 4** : *is this my address or the tokenContract address?*

**Input 5** : 0 *// I don't know which to put*

What am I missing over the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The function `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` is often used in contracts that interact with Uniswap V2 or similar DEX routers. Let's break down the parameters:

1. **`contractTokenBalance`**: This is the amount of tokens you want to swap. Make sure this value is less than or equal to the actual balance of tokens in the contract.
2. **`0`**: This is the minimum amount of ETH that must be received for the transaction to succeed. Setting it to 0 is risky because you could end up with almost nothing due to slippage. Typically, you would set this to a reasonable minimum value.
3. **`path`**: This is an array of addresses representing the path of the swap. For a direct swap from a token to ETH, the path would typically be `[tokenAddress, wethAddress]`.
4. **`address(this)`**: This is the recipient of the ETH after the swap. Typically, this would be the address of the contract executing the swap (`address(this)`). You can change this if you want the ETH to go somewhere else.
5. **`block.timestamp`**: This is the deadline after which the transaction will revert. You can set this to `block.timestamp + timeInSeconds` to give the transaction a time frame to complete.

#### Possible Issues:

1. **Gas Error**: This often means that the transaction would fail for some reason. Ensure that you have approved the Uniswap Router to spend your tokens.
2. **Contract Token Balance**: Make sure that the contract actually holds the amount of tokens specified.
3. **Slippage and Fees**: The `0` in the second parameter may be causing issues if the actual return amount is less due to fees or slippage.
4. **Address**: Make sure the path and address parameters are correct.
5. **Deadline**: Ensure that the deadline is reasonable. If you're manually inputting, perhaps set it to `block.timestamp + 60 * x` where `x` is the number of minutes you're willing to wait.

#### Example Inputs:

1. `contractTokenBalance`: `444000000000000000000000` (Make sure contract has this balance)
2. `0` (Consider changing this to a reasonable minimum)
3. `path`: `[yourTokenAddress, wbnbAddress]`
4. `address(this)` (Or another recipient address)
5. `block.timestamp + 1800` (Deadline 30 minutes from now)

Without specific code and error messages, it's hard to pinpoint the exact issue. But these are common things to look out for.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz, Thanks for the really brief and in-depth explanation.
I think this uniswap function is triggered automatically on dex (or trading rather).

just asking about that function since I thought it can be triggered manually.

Comment: Indeed it can just try some timestamp far in future use balance that is lower than your actual balance, you can use converter to calculate it depending on decimals of token you want to swap
https://www.eth-to-wei.com/

Answer (score 0):

- 1 is amount of input token
- 2 is slippage and should only be 0 if getting front run is not a concern.
- 3 is a path that needs at least 2 addresses.
- - ex. token_in, weth.
- 4 is the destination of the final token in path (or the unwraped eth in this case)
- 5 is a unix timestamp that wants to be greater than or equal to the current block unix timestamp.